What does it mean for a belief to exist?
I’m reading up on Gettier’s problem.
IEP Gettier Problem
Under the second header
2. The Justified-True-Belief Analysis of Knowledge
It states the following when elaborating on how epistemologists have traditionally defined knowledge, prior to Gettier cases:

Belief. The person believes that p. This belief might be more or less confident. And it might — but it need not — be manifested in the person’s speech, such as by her saying that p or by her saying that she believes that p. All that is needed, strictly speaking, is for her belief to exist (while possessing at least the two further properties that are about to be listed).

What is meant by this?
Are the authors stating that for a belief to “exist” it must be a thought in the mind? As in, by thinking some (p) is true; you’re instantiating a belief in (p)? Is that really all that’s needed for a belief to exist?
If that’s the case then why at all reference whether the thought is written or vocalized?

There's multiple ways people have tried to define "having a belief", some listed here: What is belief from the SEP

On the most common view, belief is a propositional attitude, that is a disposition to accept/reject some propositions p. It does not even have to take the form of "thought in the mind". Especially when the proposition is not spelled out verbally but only implicit, and the disposition manifests in acting a certain way. The reference to writing and vocalizing is there because that is the primary way for beliefs to manifest, the paradigmatic case of it, implicit forms are acknowledged due to sufficient similarities to that.

"the belief must exist" looks like an invitation to a philosophical wild goose chase. I can't speak for the author(s) of the IEP entry. The effective content is simply "She must believe that p, even if she doesn't say that p." It may be helpful to add that belief that p is a disposition to behave in certain ways, which may or may not manifest themselves. (A flammable substance is still flammable even if it never bursts into flames.)

Where do they reference whether the thought is written or vocalized? Or, perhaps, who does this?

@Conifer Travis. I think you'll find that sometimes people write "written or spoken" and sometimes they don't. But most people will assume that even when someone writes just "spoken", it is taken as read that this means "written or spoken" in the context of a discussion about belief. The reason is that it really doesn't make any difference whether the belief is written, spoken or expressed in sign language or morse code.

@LudwigV. I agree.  So, Xander meant something like, Why do people (in general) when discussing beliefs mention whether the belief has been spoken or written? [...if it doesn't matter]

@Conifer Travis. I think because there's no single word that covers both.

You asked:-

Are the authors stating that for a belief to “exist” it must be a thought in the mind? As in, by thinking some (p) is true; you’re instantiating a belief in (p)? Is that really all that’s needed for a belief to exist?

and

If that’s the case then why at all reference whether the thought is written or vocalized?

This paragraph is intended to explain the first of three conditions that explain the JTB definition of knowledge. It can be summarized as a belief that is a) true and b) justified.
A The condition is essentially "The person believes that p."
Strictly speaking "All that is needed, strictly speaking, is for her belief to exist" adds nothing to it. It is an elaborate way of introducing the qualification "(while possessing at least the two further properties that are about to be listed)." This qualification refers to the other two conditions for the JTB definition of knowledge. These two further conditions explain which beliefs count as knowledge.
The JTB defines knowledge as a belief that is a) true and b) justified.
So "This belief might be more or less confident. And it might — but it need not — be manifested in the person’s speech, such as by her saying that p or by her saying that she believes that p." is not about the definition of knowledge, but about the definition of belief.
The paragraph is anticipating questions that the reader might be asking - specifically, whether a belief that one is not sure about counts and whether it is essential that one expresses the belief by stating it.
But when you ask your first question, you do raise the question of the definition of belief. In one way, the answer is that when you believe something, you certainly do think that it is true. But that doesn't answer the last part of your first question.
The answer to that is that belief means that we will, in the right circumstances, express or manifest our belief a) in language, spoken or written, and b) in non-verbal actions - because we will act on our belief when it is relevant.
It seems to follow that, if the right circumstances never arise, we will never express or manifest the belief. You may well ask what the belief amounts to if that's the case. The answer is to point out that something flammable is flammable even if it never bursts into flames. Beliefs are like that.
The fundamental issue at the back of this is the fundamental question in the philosophy of mind, about Cartesian dualism, behaviourism, etc. This is not the place to go in to that, so I shall leave it there.

I appreciate you taking the time to respond, and I definitely see what you're saying about anticipating what the reader might question. As for the latter part of your response, I concur - the flammability analogy was a nice touch.

I'm glad you found it helpful. I thought the paragraph was quite badly written, but there was no way to explain it by going through all the details.

The only requirement for something to exist is that it must be observable, i.e. it has to have some effect on the causal flow of events.
A belief becomes observable in the behaviour of the believer. We do different things depending on what we believe.
